# Rewrite User-Agent to all Open URI Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, user-agent, open-uri

Using Rails `4.2.10`

I would like to open image from URL thanks to `mongoid` `papaerclip` and `open_uri`

It perfectly works in 95% of use cases but some website send me a 404 when they see the `user-agent` of the request is `Ruby`.

The problem is with the lib `paperclip`=>
`paperclip/io_adapters/uri_adapter.rb in download_content at line 48`

```
def download_content
    options = { read_timeout: Paperclip.options[:read_timeout] }.compact

    open(@target, **options)
end
```

If I could add here an option it would be great but I don't think it's possible so I would like to add a default header with my `user-agent`to all request done by `open_uri`

Comment: Didn't see the option to set a header to all requests but the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) does show how to set headers for a specific request. Wrapping the requests in a method, which always sets the header should give you what you want.

Comment: Yes, but how can I manage to do this as it is a dependency I can't modify this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily for your use case there is no such thing as a class being closed against modification in ruby.

Add a patch to your rails app in an initializer. The structure is roughly as follows:

In `config/initializers/some_arbitrary_name.rb`

```
module UriAdapterPatch
  def open(url, options)
    # alter the objects however you want
    super(altered_or_original_url, altered_or_original_options)
  end
end

Paperclip::UriAdapter.prepend(UriAdapterPatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for `paperclip-3.5.4`

```
module Paperclip
  class UriAdapter < AbstractAdapter
    def download_content
      open(@target,"User-Agent" => "Your Custom User Agent")
    end
  end
end

# for example put it in config/initializers/paperclip_user_agent.rb
```

For other versions just write in project folder

```
gem which paperclip
```

and find in path from output file `paperclip/io_adapters/uri_adapter.rb`

There is function `def download_content`, it is your aim to rewrite

Comment: Notice, that it is not great solution. It's just monkeypatch